# How to serialize form in jquery while having it as object

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I already have form object like this in a variable:

```
<form method="post" id="modal_form1" action="http://localhost/bookmark/post_crud_model_form">...</form>
```

How can I serialize it using jQuery only?

**JS**

```
function submit_form(form){

    var se = String(form);
    console.log($(se).serialize());
}
```

**Form in Console**

```
<form method="post" id="modal_form1" action="http://localhost/bookmark/post_crud_model_form"><input type="hidden" id="input1" value="1"><div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Link</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" value="FIRST LINK"></div><div class="form-group">
                <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Category</label><select class="form-control"><option>cat 1</option><option value="1">cat 1</option><option value="2">cat 2</option><option value="3">cat 3</option><option value="4">cat 4</option></select></div><div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Detail</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" value="ASDASDASASF"></div><div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Created_at</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" value="2019-01-12 22:25:21"></div><div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Updated_at</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" value="2019-01-12 22:25:21"></div><div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="submit_form(this.form);" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
    </div></form>
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" onclick="submit_form(this.form);" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
    </div>';


    $return .= '</form>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your code. Firstly you're sending a Form Element object to the `submit_form()` function which you then attempt to coerce to a string. This is the source of your error. If you skip that step, the jQuery object can be created correctly.

Secondly to serialise data in a `form` all the fields must have `name` attributes on them, so you need to amend your HTML. Once those points are addressed, the logic works fine.

Also note that I changed the button to a submit so that the form is submit and then hooked a an unobtrusive event handler to listen for that event on the `form`. You should not be using `on*` event attributes at all as they are incredibly outdated.

```js
$('#modal_form1').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).serialize());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="modal_form1" action="http://localhost/bookmark/post_crud_model_form"><input type="hidden" id="input1" value="1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Link</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" value="FIRST LINK" name="link"></div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Category</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="category">
      <option>cat 1</option>
      <option value="1">cat 1</option>
      <option value="2">cat 2</option>
      <option value="3">cat 3</option>
      <option value="4">cat 4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Detail</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" value="ASDASDASASF" name="detail"></div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Created_at</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" value="2019-01-12 22:25:21" name="created_at"></div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Updated_at</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" value="2019-01-12 22:25:21" name="updated_at"></div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="send_message">Send message</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: it's not doing it

Comment: jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLFormElement]
    at Function.oe.error (jquery.min.js:2)
    at oe.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
    at oe.select (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.oe [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
    at new w.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w (jquery.min.js:2)
    at submit_form (crud.js:7)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (searchpage:1)

Comment: In which case please add a more clear example of the code you currently have to the question. As you can see in the example above, this works absolutely fine.

Comment: That's not really helping, we need to see what the type and value of `form` is when it's passed in to your `submit_form()` function

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my answer for you now the problem is much clearer